# Can't get tests working with Selenium, Capybara-webkit; RackTest works fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, capybara, rspec2, capybara-webkit

I have this integration spec:

```
feature "When buying a deal, a user" do
  let(:current_market) { Factory.create(:market) }
  let(:deal) { Factory.create(:deal_with_products, market: current_market) }

  scenario "can change quanitity and see an updated total" do
    visit_checkout_for_product deal.products.first
    # ...
  end

  # ...
end

def visit_checkout_for_product(product)
  visit deal_path current_market, product.deal
  choose product.title
  click_button 'buy now'
end
```

This works wonderfully with `RackTest`, but when I change the spec to:

```
  scenario "can change quanitity and see an updated total", js: true do
    visit_checkout_for_product deal.products.first
    # ...
  end
```

My tests break, giving me a `500 Internal Server` error like so:

[image]

I can't seem to find anyway to get a stack trace, but I'm reasonably sure that `nil:NilClass` should be the `deal` let variable defined earlier.

What I can't understand is why this isn't a problem at all with `RackTest`... is there some additional configuration I'm missing here?

I'm using `RSpec 2.8.0` and `Rails 3.1.1`. Please let me know if you need to see any other files.

Answer (score 3):

The issue was [database_cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner), which wasn't configured correctly, as it was wiping my test data before the Selenium/capybara-webkit tests were running.  Here's the config that I'm now using that's allowing everything to pass:

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
  config.before(:each) { DatabaseCleaner.start }
  config.after(:each) { DatabaseCleaner.clean }
end
```

Comment: Thanks!  Was having the same issue.  I was using transactional.  Changing to truncation fixed it up.